# Rewriting an Apache redirect rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

How do I write a generic redirect rule that does something like this:

```
/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=51574
```

becomes:

```
/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=51574
```

In other words, the argument values for f and t are placeholders

This would be a permanent redirect so I think I have that figured out.

Comment: The first is the request. This is mostly a concern for search engines, since the forum is huge (290,000 posts).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work generically:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 /phpBB2(.*) /forum$1
```

It echoes all URL arguments, which should be fine in this case because I am not aware of any arguments for phpBB2 that don't work for phpBB3.

[This tool](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/index.php) helped.