# Using HTACCESS to rewrite index.html AND redirect http://site.com to http://www.site.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

In .htaccess I see how to rewrite **/index.html** to point to the main domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.html?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ "/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I also understand how .htaccess can prevent the site from being indexed under WWW and without it

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mycustomcloset.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mycustomcloset.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

But how do you do both at the same time?

In other words, I'd like **mycustomcloset.com** and **mycustomcloset.com/index.html** both to point to **http://www.mycustomcloset.com**.

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723942/rewriting-an-apache-redirect-rule/15724022#15724022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand the first code on your question, however you can still try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,NE]
```

Now, if you also want to redirect *mycustomcloset.com/index.html* and *www.mycustomcloset.com/index.html* into *www.mycustomcloset.com* then you can try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,NE]

RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.mycustomcloset.com [R,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to make your code also redirect http://www.mycustomcloset.com/index.html to http://www.mycustomcloset.com?

Comment: @JayFrostWebDesign Please check my updates! Just don't forget to accept an exact answer to notify the viewers.