# .htaccess redirection to a sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please help in setting up a .htaccess / mod_rewrite redirection which will:

-> redirect example.com to example.com/forum/ and

-> redirect example.com/any-posts.php to example.com/forum/any-posts.php

actually I created a forum a month ago which was being accessed at 'example.com' but now need to redirect everything to /forum/ so that it works like: example.com/forum/ folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you must rewrite the url

the .htaccess should be

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forum/$1 [L]
```

and you get example.com to example.com/forum/

Comment: Thanks Zach but will it also work for:
example.com/any-posts.php to example.com/forum/any-posts.php

Comment: Works for everything.... 
example.com/any-posts.php to example.com/forum/any-posts.php
example.com/anything... to example.com/forum/anything...

Comment: check this maybe can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723942/rewriting-an-apache-redirect-rule/15724022#15724022