# How to use [NE] with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following file in my filesystem

```
/http/domain/www.punchedin.com/hello%20world.txt
```

notice the %20 is literal and should not be converted to a space.

The file can be accessed using the following URL

```
http://www.punchedin.com/domain/www.punchedin.com/hello%2520world.txt
```

I have the following .htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /domain/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,L]
```

I would like to be able to access the file using the following URL

```
http://www.punchedin.com/home/hello%2520world.txt
```

But it always returns a 404 error.

I have a partial Answer to my question, to get it to return the file I have to double encode the URL like this...

```
http://www.punchedin.com/home/hello%252520world.txt
```

Any ideas how I can avoid double encoding the URL?

Comment: may be this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723942/rewriting-an-apache-redirect-rule/15724022#15724022

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

To solve the problem I needed to avoid double decoding of the URL. To accomplish this I replace the original /home redirect with a modfied one that uses THE_REQUEST instead..

I replaced this line...

```
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /domain/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,L]
```

With These...

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(\S*)\s/home/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /domain/%{HTTP_HOST}/%2 [L]
```

THE_REQUEST is the raw request so nothing has been URL decoded yet with it